# radiobuttonlist in updatepanel both dynamically created don't retain value on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm dynamically creating controls on my page (aspx) using the code below, but when the asynchronous postback triggers the radio button doesn't retain it's selection and the method uptheup doesn't get called. I'm guessing it's to do with the view state not returning the values, but I thought if the control ID was the same and it's created in Page_Init the in Page_Load the value should automatically be set from view state??

What I want is if someone selects No for the textbox to become visible.  The control IDs are set from a database and are the same each time it loads as the code is used several times (I've replaced the IDs for easy reading below)

the following is called from Page_Init

```
RadioButtonList rbtnl = new RadioButtonList();
                        rbtnl.ID = "rbl_1";
                        rbtnl.Items.Add("Yes");
                        rbtnl.Items.Add("No");
                        rbtnl.AutoPostBack = true;
                        rbtnl.EnableViewState = true;
                        rbtnl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(uptheup);
                        rbtnl.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.AutoID;
                        scriptmanager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(rbtnl);

                        TextBox tbx = new TextBox();
                        tbx.ID = "tb-1";
                        tbx.CssClass = "form-control";
                        tbx.Visible = false;

                        UpdatePanel upx = new UpdatePanel();
                        upx.ID = "up-1";
                        upx.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(rbtnl);
                        upx.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(tbx);
                        upx.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Always;
                        upx.EnableViewState = true;
                        upx.ChildrenAsTriggers = true;


                        plcEvalBody.Controls.Add(upx);
```

Comment: Anyone able to help? Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so the code is fine and it works well, the issue was me assuming the IDs weren't the issue - they are - NEVER USE $ in control ID's. I'd used this to separate two sections of the ID and it is not valid.